# how to change eclipse html formatting

Tags: html, eclipse, formatting

When i open an html file in eclipse, after i format it, it looks like this:

```
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="memberName">Login Name:</label> <input type="text"
                    name="memberName" id="memberName" value=""
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> <label
                    for="memberPass">Password:</label> <input type="password"
                    name="memberPass" id="memberPass" value=""
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />


            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

but i want each tag with all of its attributes on the same line

how do i make eclipse understand that?

Comment: This is called _word wrap_. Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3242397/1763929)

Comment: You need to stop Eclipse from line wrapping. See these other SO questions: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890805/stop-eclipse-from-line-wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890805/stop-eclipse-from-line-wrapping) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005929/howto-prevent-eclipse-from-line-wrapping-in-xml-and-html-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005929/howto-prevent-eclipse-from-line-wrapping-in-xml-and-html-files)

Answer (score 9):

To change the formatting as usual, go to Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor, and remove all inline Elements like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Under

> Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor

there are some options in terms of HTML formatting.

In comparison to Java, there are almost no options available, but maybe you can figure out on what to do.

Comment: I could not. I hope there is an option for that.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor**

1. Remove all inline elements
2. Set Line width to 200 or more
3. set indentation size at 1

**Apply and Close**, Now format your code by pressing **ctrl+Shift+F**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer here [how to turn off break line in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242360/how-to-turn-off-break-line-in-eclipse/3242397#3242397)

Follow these steps to **Not wrap.**

> Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter. Create new formatter. Click on edit and then pick tab Line Wrapping and set Line Wrapping policy to Do not wrap.